# Shown semicontinuity for a subsequence, how to get it for the whole sequence?

Tags: functional-analysis

Here I work on a reflexive Banach space $U$ (some Lebesgue space). Let $u_n \to u$ and let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. I have shown that there is a subsequence $n_j$ such that
$$f(u) \leq \liminf_{n_j \to \infty}f(u_{n_j})$$
i.e. that $f$ is lower semicts on a subsequence. Is there any way to conclude 
$$f(u) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}f(u_{n})$$
i.e. that $f$ is properly lower semicontinuous? What more do I need to assume to get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This already implies lower semicontinuity of the function; at least, if you did not only prove that there exists such a subsequence for some specific sequence $u_n \to u$, but for any sequence $u_n \to u$.

Let $u_n \to u$ an arbitrary sequence. From the very definition of limes inferior, it follows that we can choose a subsequence $(u_{n_j})$ such that

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(u_n) = \lim_{j \to \infty} f(u_{n_j}). \tag{1}$$

You have shown that there exists a subsequence of $(u_{n_{j_k}})_k$ of $(u_{n_j})_j$ such that

$$f(u) \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} f(u_{n_{j_k}}) \tag{2}.$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields

$$f(u) \stackrel{(2)}{\leq} \liminf_{k \to \infty} f(u_{n_{j_k}}) = \lim_{j \to \infty} f(u_{n_j}) \stackrel{(1)}{=} \liminf_{n \to \infty} f(u_n).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For equation (1) don't we need $f(u_n)$ to be a bounded sequence though?

Comment: Also I don't understand why $\liminf f(u_{n_{j_k}}) = \lim f(u_{n_j})$.

Comment: @asda. No, if $\liminf_n f(u_n) = \infty$, then the claim is trival. And the other one follows from the fact that if a sequence $f_j$ converges to $f$, then $f_{j_k} \to f$ for any subsequence $(f_{j_k})_k$ of $(f_j)_j$. (Apply this to $f_j := f(u_{n_j})$.)